# Problema al importar base de datos con phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Tengo una Base de Datos con tablas innodb en mi servidor local. Las tablas, tienen claves primarias, indices y relaciones.

Necesito alojarla en un Hosting web que tiene soporte para tablas innodb.

Cuando la exporto desde mi servidor local, lo hace correctamente. El problema aparece cuando la importo desde el Hosting web; si bien no arroja errores, no replica los indices y relaciones.

¿Alguna sugerencia para resolver eso?

Gracias.

Comment: _"Exportar"_ generalmente es crear un script que contiene las instrucciones para realizar una _"copia"_ de la base de datos. este script, ¿tiene las instrucciones para crear esos índices y relaciones que te interesan?

Comment: @ jachguate, te comento que lo exporto desde phpmyadmin, y se genera un archivo .sql que contiene los scripts, a eso te referis?

Comment: Exacto, a eso mismo.

Comment: @jachguate como hago para adjuntar el archivo ,sql ? o te lo envío a alguna dirección, no sé si puede.

Comment: No creo que haga falta que lo adjuntes, míralo y responde mi pregunta. Si lo consideras necesario, edita tu pregunta y añade el código, pero te adelanto que si tiene más de lo mínimo necesario, difícilmente alguien lo leerá. La idea es que tu aisles el problema. Mira el tema [mcve] en el centro de ayuda para más información.